# Cannot import urllib.request and urllib.parse

Tags: python, import, import-libraries

I will be grateful for any help. I use Python 3.4.1 and I try to import urllib.request and urllib.parse. Without success. I always receive:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/x/Documents/PROGRAMING and MODELING/Phyton/find cure words/importowanie.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import urllib.parse
>   File "C:/Users/x/Documents/PROGRAMING and MODELING/Phyton/find cure words\urllib.py", line 1, in <module>
>     import urllib.request
> ImportError: No module named 'urllib.request'; 'urllib' is not a package
> ```

I guess the problem is with importing but I don't know how to go around it

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you’re using Python 3?

Comment: Did you name your file `urllib.py` ?

Comment: Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>>

Comment: And the file is not urllib.py

Comment: You should look into requests. Much easier t work with than urllib. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the actual code, I am guessing based on my past experience with such an error.

I presume you are trying to import `urllib.parse` in a file called `importowanie.py` in `C:/Users/x/Documents/PROGRAMING and MODELING/Phyton/find cure words`. When Python tries to import a module by the name `urllib`, it first checks in the same folder from where you are trying to import. In your case, it sees that there is a module called `urllib` in the same folder from where you are trying to import it. It sees inside that module instead of the "real" urllib. As it sees nothing called **parse** inside your `urllib` it raises an error.
It is because of a file called `urllib.py` in `C:/Users/x/Documents/PROGRAMING and MODELING/Phyton/find cure words`.

So a solution would be to rename `urllib` in the above directory to something else and try again.

Comment: So easy so good. It's only pity that I spend hours to figure it out.
Thanks a lot Saimadhav Heblikar

Comment: Don't forget to mark Saimadhav's comment as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had trouble installing urllib.parse as well. You can manually include the source, which worked for me: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/urllib/parse.py

Go to the source link, copy the source, save it in it's appropriate file name/format, import it and you're good to go.

EDIT: wrong link

Comment: Please add meaningful code and description here. Don't just link to the site - otherwise, this answer will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible.